# fluent nhibernate deep clone error on mono 2.10.5

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, mono, deep-copy

I'm using fluent nhibernate on my project. Internally, fluent nhibernate use this code below to perform `DeepClone` ([reference](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/blob/master/src/FluentNHibernate/Utils/Extensions.cs)) :

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream()) {
    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

    formatter.Serialize(stream, obj);
    stream.Position = 0;

    return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work on **mono** because those code will call

```
System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<T>.GetObjectData 
(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext 
context)
```

which not yet implemented (throw `NotImplementedException`).

Does anyone know deep clone codes that works on mono ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should report a bug in bugzilla.xamarin.com (with a title like "FluentNHibernate doesn't work with Mono" or something, rather than focusing just on the NIE which they already may know about).

Comment: Looking at source code, Mono doesn't implement `GetObjectData`. I'll accept this as an answer.

Comment: It seems that bug is not present from version 3.0 of mono.